# Use Gram-Schmidt process on Chebychev polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonal-polynomials

I need help using the Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization process to derive the first four orthonormal Chebychev polynomials. Using the range $[-1,1]$ and the weight function $w(x)=(1-x^2)^\frac{1}{2}$.

I know I can follow the Gram-Schmidt process using [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process)
but I am unsure how to start this problem with the Chebychev polynomials, meaning what would be my $u(1)$ and $u(2)$?

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773). Also are you sure of your weight ? Is it $w(x)=(1-x^2)^\frac{1}{2}$ or $w(x)=(1-x^2)^{ {\color{blue} -}\frac{1}{2}}$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Gram-Schmidt process can be used to orthonormalize any linearly independent family of vectors. Since you want to end up with polynomials, you could pick the family of monomials $\{1,x,x^2,x^3,\ldots\}$ and start orthonormalizing with respect to your inner product.